How to extract information from a photo of a document
I want to build a simple tool that will allow a user to take a photo of a document and extract information such as date/time and some other information
It is simple to do this through Chat GPT's UI, upload an image, ask it for some information from the document. But is just calling Chat GPT's API from my code really a viable solution?

It just feels like a black box that is liable to change without notice, i.e. fragile.
I assumed I'd need to train and deploy my own model, is using chat gpt expensive overkill for what I want to do? If I somehow ended up with a lot of users I'm thinking this would become a problem.

Note: I have no real AI experience or knowledge, but I do have lots of programming experience (I work full time as a developer).

Extracting text from images is a standard task, there are many tools available, the search term OCR (optical character recognition) should be a good start for your research. Using ChatGPT's API shouldn't be necessary here.

There are several ways to go about it but you can start of with Ollama, you need to download a model such as llama3, if you have experience with python you are in luck.
You don't need to train a model, there are different models out there that does what you need or solves this kind of problem, all you need to do is provided the llm your documents(images, text, pdfs etc) and ask questions on them.
However in some cases, if your pdf contains financial information such as annuity and the likes , You might need to train it for it to understand how to do those kind of calculations or better still write a function which inherits from Langchain_tool to instruct the llm on how to use it for those specific cases.

It just feels like a black box that is liable to change without
notice, i.e. fragile. I assumed I'd need to train and deploy my own
model, is using chat gpt expensive overkill for what I want to do? If
I somehow ended up with a lot of users I'm thinking this would become
a problem.

Here are the general steps on how to go go about it:
Step 1:
First download Ollama then you can pull the llama image which would serve as your llm, do a docker pull of llama, preferably llama3.
Step 2:
Find a library that converts images to text or pdf such as
Optical character recognition Library (OCR)
Step 3:
Find a vector_db(FAISS, chromadb and the likes) which converts text to vectors; this makes information extraction easy.
Step 4:
Feed your documents to the vector_db so it can convert it to vectors because numbers are good...

Thanks for this - why is a vector db necessary? Would using one mean that I wouldn't query the llm with natural language text?

You're welcome @handles it usually makes information retrieval faster. You know computer are kinda of bad with NLP, so converting words to vectors and mapping each word to a vector in the vector space makes it relatively easy to query using KNN (k-nearest neighbors) algo. The vector db stores the vectors and you can use the llm to query it more like sql kinda. so llm sends a query(words) it is convert by a tokenzier see_ref then sent to the db the information sent back.

You don't need to train a model to just extract text from documents/images, you can simply use python libraries like pytesseract etc.
By simply using 10 lines of code you can extract all the information.
You can integrate this model/code to your tool.
You can ask ChatGPT for a reference code.

Thanks - the documents will vary quite a lot. Looking at tesseract I can see that yes it will successfully pull the text out, but I need a component that will "understand" the text so that it can provide a a summary of part of it and a date and time.
